What is the best way to filter groups by conditionally checking the values of the first row of each group only?
This is my DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'group': list('xxxxyyy'),
        'open': [100, 150, 200, 160, 300, 150, 170],
        'close': [105, 150, 200, 160, 350, 150, 170],
        'stop': [104, 104, 104, 104, 400, 400, 400]
    }
)

Expected output is returning group x based on the group column:
  group  open  close  stop
0     x   100    105   104
1     x   150    150   104
2     x   200    200   104
3     x   160    160   104

Logic:
I want to check if df.stop.iloc[0] for each group is between df.open.iloc[0] and df.close.iloc[0]. And if it is between these two, I want to return that entire group.
This is my attempt. It works but I think there is a better way to do it. Note that in the if clause, both conditions are needed to be checked.
def func(df):
    s = df.stop.iloc[0]
    o = df.open.iloc[0]
    c = df.close.iloc[0]

    if (o <= s <= c) or (c <= s <= o):
        return df

out = df.groupby('group').apply(func).reset_index(drop=True)


You could groupby.first, then build a mask with isin:
tmp = df.groupby('group').first()
keep = tmp.index[tmp['stop'].between(tmp['open'], tmp['close'])
                |tmp['stop'].between(tmp['close'], tmp['open'])
                ]
df[df['group'].isin(keep)]

Output:
  group  open  close  stop
0     x   100    105   104
1     x   150    150   104
2     x   200    200   104
3     x   160    160   104

Intermediate tmp:
       open  close  stop  o<=s<=c  c<=s<=o     OR
group                                            
x       100    105   104     True    False   True
y       300    350   400    False    False  False

with groupby.filter:
def func(df):
    s = df.stop.iloc[0]
    o = df.open.iloc[0]
    c = df.close.iloc[0]

    return (o <= s <= c) or (c <= s <= o)

df.groupby('group').filter(func)

separate groups:
g = df.groupby('group')
tmp = g.first()

keep = tmp.index[tmp['stop'].between(tmp['open'], tmp['close'])
                |tmp['stop'].between(tmp['close'], tmp['open'])
                ]

for x in keep:
    print(f'group {x}')
    print(g.get_group(x))

Output:
group x
  group  open  close  stop
0     x   100    105   104
1     x   150    150   104
2     x   200    200   104
3     x   160    160   104

without groupby
For this particular case, you can even skip the groupby and replace it with drop_duplicates:
tmp = df.drop_duplicates('group')
keep = tmp.loc[tmp['stop'].between(tmp['open'], tmp['close'])
              |tmp['stop'].between(tmp['close'], tmp['open']),
               'group']

out = df[df['group'].isin(keep)]

timings
Tested on ~ 7K rows with groups of 3 rows
# filter
266 ms ± 10.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# groupby.first + isin
1.63 ms ± 24.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# drop_duplicates + isin
1.34 ms ± 34.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)


if (o <= s <= c) or (c <= s <= o): what about this?

@AmirX I see, do you want a single DataFrame as output or a list of them?

A single dataframe with multiple groups probably. In my data I might have multiple groups that meet this condition

see the updated answer

Do you personally prefer the first solution or the second one that is with filter?

@AmirX it depends if you want efficiency or conciseness

When I wanted to do that my instinct was the one with filter.  First one is faster?

If efficiency is a concern, then use drop_duplicates (see update)

For a large dataframe filter is quite slower. I added timings

You do not necessarily need df.groupby for this:
m = (df['stop'].between(df['open'], df['close']) | 
     df['stop'].between(df['close'], df['open'])
     ) & (~df.duplicated())

out = df[df['group'].isin(df.loc[m, 'group'])]

Output:
  group  open  close  stop
0     x   100    105   104
1     x   150    150   104
2     x   200    200   104
3     x   160    160   104

Explanation

Check Series.between for both sides & combine with a filter that keeps only the first row per group (using ~ + df.duplicated).
Use the resulting boolean series (m) to select from df['group'] using df.loc only where there is any True.

df.loc[m, 'group']

0    x
Name: group, dtype: object


Next, pass that result to Series.isin applied to df['group'].

Of course, this method will follow the original index, rather than sort the groups. But in OP's example the data is already sorted.

That's partially true. Yes groupby is somewhat slow, but the way you did it considers all rows and OP's function considered only the first row of each group. If you don't want to groupby you can use drop_duplicates (see my update) ;)

Yeah. I wanted to say that too :) I wanted to check the first row only.

Yeah, missed that part initially, but should work with the update. But also with the update of @mozway, of course :).
